# AngularJs & Tokens

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jwt

I'm using AngularJs with JWT Auth. I've already made an api and I've test it.

With every request the api expect a token and with every response it gives a token object back. But when I try it like this:

```
employeeAppModule.config([
        '$httpProvider',
        function ($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {
                var token, headers, $cookies;

                //inject cookies
                angular.injector(['ngCookies']).invoke(['$cookies', function(_$cookies_) {
                    $cookies = _$cookies_;
                }]);

                return {
                    request: function (request) {
                        token = $cookies.get('jwt-token');
                        headers = request.headers || (request.headers = {});

                        if(token != null && token != 'undefined') {
                            headers.Authorization = token;
                        }
                        return request;
                    },
                    response: function (response) {
                        if (typeof response.data.result === 'undefined') {
                            return response;
                        }

                        if(response.status && response.status.code === 401) {
                            alert('token wordt verwijderd');
                        }

                        if(response.data && response.data.result.token && response.data.result.token.length > 10) {
                            $cookies.put('jwt-token', 'Bearer ' + response.data.result.token);
                        }
                        return response;
                    }
                };
            });
        }]);
```

It's not working. If I put a couple of alert boxes between the request/ response it's working. How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `Authorization` property on the `headers` variable and then you return `request`.

```
request.headers = headers;
return request;
```

This should solve the problem.

A couple of things though:

- Don't put `Bearer` in the cookie itself, just add it to your header on every request, it's more elegant.
- I'm not sure whether it's intended, but you really shouldn't return a token object on every single request. If it's the intended behavior, then my bad!

Comment: It makes sense to return a new token at every call if you intend to regularly update the information inside it, for example you want to extend the validity of the token as long as the user is active.

Comment: That was just an opinion. Although I would argue whether that's the best way to extend a session. Obviously the rest of your claims (pun intended) are true! :)